# Rbind corresponding elements in two or more lists in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rbind

I have 3 lists, each with 500 elements. Here for demonstrative purposes, I have 2 lists with 1 element each:

```
structure(list(timeseries = c(1, 7, 59), t = c(1, 3, 7)), .Names = c("timeseries", "t"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")   

structure(list(timeseries = c(5, 6, 7), t = c(8, 9, 10)), .Names = c("timeseries", "t"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

My aim is to rbind the first element in list 1 with the first element in list 2 and 3. Then, the second element in list 1 with the second element in list 2 and 3. And so on.

In my example, I would end up with a list of this form

```
structure(list(timeseries = c(1,7,59,5, 6, 7), t = c(1,3,7,8, 9, 10)), .Names = c("timeseries", "t"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I do this?

Thank you!

****EDIT*** Improved example of the intended outcome. I have a and b. I want to obtain C.

```
a<-list(structure(list(timeseries = c(1, 7, 59), t = c(1, 3, 7)), .Names = c("timeseries", "t"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"),
structure(list(timeseries = c(1, 7, 59), t = c(1, 3, 7)), .Names = c("timeseries", "t"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"))


b<-list(structure(list(timeseries = c(2, 3, 5), t = c(2, 4, 6)), .Names = c("timeseries", "t"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"),
        structure(list(timeseries = c(60, 70, 80), t = c(20, 30, 40)), .Names = c("timeseries", "t"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"))


c<-list(structure(list(timeseries = c(1, 7, 59, 2,3, 5), t = c(1, 3, 7, 2, 4, 6)), .Names = c("timeseries", "t"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"),
        structure(list(timeseries = c(1, 7, 59, 60, 70, 80), t = c(1, 3, 7, 20, 30, 40)), .Names = c("timeseries", "t"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `do.call("rbind", list(lst1, lst2))` ?

Comment: No, the final list must contain the same number of elements present in the original lists. In my example, 1

Comment: What do you mean by similar number of elements? `do.call("rbind", list(lst1, lst2))` gives same output as your expected output or you can also use `bind_rows(lst1, lst2)`  from `dplyr`.

Comment: Please make your example inputs more representative of the real data, and provide expected output. At the moment `rbind` gives exactly the output you want.

Comment: Also, fix your wording, you mean data.frame when you say list, and you mean column when you say elements. And give object names to your input `x1 <- structure(...`, `x2 <- structure(...`, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming length of `a` and `b` is the same we can do

```
lapply(seq_along(a), function(x) rbind(a[[x]], b[[x]]))

#[[1]]
#  timeseries t
#1          1 1
#2          7 3
#3         59 7
#4          2 2
#5          3 4
#6          5 6

#[[2]]
#  timeseries  t
#1          1  1
#2          7  3
#3         59  7
#4         60 20
#5         70 30
#6         80 40
```

`seq_along` generates sequence from 1 to length of the object. If you do

```
seq_along(a) #you would get output as
#[1] 1 2
```

as `length(a)` is 2. So we `rbind` the dataframe one by one `rbind(a[[1]], b[[1]])` first, then `rbind(a[[2]], b[[2]])` and so on. `lapply` ensures the final output is a list.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. How does the seq_along work here?

Comment: @JPV added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Just try the map2 function :

```
purrr::map2(a,b,rbind) -> d
identical(c,d)
# [1] TRUE
```